# Failed to read an adapted Java Bean property Soap ui

Tags: soapui

I have created the project in Soap UI 5.0.0. It is working fine on my machine.. But when some uses 4.5.1, not able to open the request. Is it due to the lower version? Can any one have the solution

```
ERROR:com.jgoodies.binding.beans.PropertyAccessException: Failed to read an adapted Java Bean property.
cause=org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.XmlValueOutOfRangeException: string value 'No Authorization' is not a valid enumeration value for type of authType element in Credentials in namespace http://eviware.com/soapui/config
bean=com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.WsdlTestRequest@68b9f71b
bean type=com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.WsdlTestRequest
property name=authType
property type=java.lang.String
property reader=public java.lang.String com.eviware.soapui.impl.support.AbstractHttpRequest.getAuthType()
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The authType enum was modified for SoapUI v5 and the "No Authorization" value was added.  Hence, projects created in v5 and opened with v4 will not recognize this value.  The fix is to change "No Authorization" to the equivalent v4 value of "Global HTTP Settings".  Do this manually in the project XML files.

This value will only work in v5:
    No Authorization
Equivalent value in v4:
    Global HTTP Settings

Note: if you open in v5 and close SoapUI, it will save the project automatically and revert this change.